# Redux not working on React Native (Invariant Violation)

Tags: reactjs, native

**Error Message:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aw7gL.jpg

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Layout from './containers/Layout/Layout';

import store from './store/index';

export default function App() {

    return (

      <Provider store={store}><Layout/></Provider>

    );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**index.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducer';

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

**reducer.js**

```
import * as actionTypes from './actions';
import moment from 'moment';

const initialState = {

    itemList: [],
    idCount: 0,
    text: 'Write your to do item!',
    chosenDate: 'no-date',
    activeItems: 0,
    completedItems: 0,
    showCompletedList: false

}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

    switch(action.type){

        case actionTypes.ADDTOLIST:

            const objItem = { 'id': state.idCount+1, 'text': state.text, 'date': state.chosenDate, 'completed': false, 'displayTextInput': false, 'pickerVisible': false };
            return {
                ...state, 
                itemList: [...state.itemList, objItem],
                idCount: state.idCount+1,
                activeItems: state.activeItems+1
            }

        case actionTypes.REMOVEFROMLIST:

            let oldItemList = [...state.itemList];
            let index = oldItemList.indexOf(action.item);

            if( index !== -1) oldItemList.splice(index, 1);

            return {
                ...state,
                itemList: [...oldItemList],
                activeItems: action.item.completed ?  state.activeItems : state.activeItems-1,
                completedItems: action.item.completed ?  state.completedItems-1 : state.completedItems
            }

        case actionTypes.EDITITEMDATE:

            oldItemList = [...state.itemList];
            index = oldItemList.indexOf(action.item);

            if(index !== -1){
                oldItemList[index].date = state.chosenDate;
                return {
                    ...state,
                    itemList: [...oldItemList]
                }
            }

            return state;

        case actionTypes.EDITITEMSTATUS:

            oldItemList = [...state.itemList];
            index = oldItemList.indexOf(action.item);

            if(index !== -1){
                oldItemList[index].completed = !oldItemList[index].completed;
                return {
                    ...state,
                    itemList: [...oldItemList],
                    activeItems: action.item.completed ?  state.activeItems+1 : state.activeItems-1,
                    completedItems: action.item.completed ?  state.completedItems-1 : state.completedItems+1
                }
            }

            return state;

        case actionTypes.EDITITEMTEXT:

            oldItemList = [...state.itemList];
            index = oldItemList.indexOf(action.item);

            if(index !== -1){
                oldItemList[index] = state.text;
                return {
                    ...state,
                    itemList: [...oldItemList]
                }
            }

            return state;

        case actionTypes.TOGGLETEXTINPUT:

            oldItemList = [...oldItemList];
            index = oldItemList[index].indexOf(action.item);

            if(index !== -1){
                oldItemList[index],displayTextInput = !oldItemList[index],displayTextInput;
                return {
                    ...state,
                    itemList: [...oldItemList]
                }
            }

            return state;

        case actionTypes.FILTERACTIVEITEMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                showCompletedList: false
            }

        case actionTypes.FILTERCOMPLETEDITEMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                showCompletedList: true
            }

        case actionTypes.HANDLECHANGETEXT:
            return {
                ...state,
                text: action.text
            }

        case actionTypes.HIDEPICKERINITEM:

            oldItemList = [...state.itemList];
            index = oldItemList[index].indexOf(item);

            if(index !== -1){
                oldItemList[index].isVisible = false;
                return {
                    ...state,
                    itemList: [...oldItemList]
                }
            }

        case actionTypes.SHOWPICKERINITEM:

                oldItemList = [...state.itemList];
                index = oldItemList[index].indexOf(item);

                if(index !== -1){
                    oldItemList[index].isVisible = true;
                    return {
                        ...state,
                        itemList: [...oldItemList]
                    }
                }

                return state;

        case actionTypes.HANDLEPICKER:

            return{
                ...state,
                chosenDate: moment(action.datetime).format('MMM, Do YYYY HH:mm') 
            }

    }

}

export default reducer;
```

**Layout.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import AddScreen from '../../components/AddScreen/AddScreen';
import TodoList from '../../components/TodoList/TodoList';
import Header from '../../components/UI/Header/Header';

class Layout extends Component {

    state = {

        displayItems: false,
        pickerVisible: false

    }

    toggleItems = () => {
        this.setState({ displayItems: !this.state.displayItems });
    }

    showPicker = () => {
        this.setState({ pickerVisible: true });
    }

    hidePicker = () => {
        this.setState({ pickerVisible: false });
    }

    render () {

        let childComponent = <AddScreen 
                                toggleItems={this.props.toggleItems}
                                showPicker={this.props.showPicker}
                                hidePicker={this.props.hidePicker}
                                pickerVisible={this.props.pickerVisible}

                                />;

        if(this.props.displayItems){

            childComponent = <TodoList 
                                itemList={this.state.itemList} 
                                showCompletedList={this.state.showCompletedList}

                                />;

        }

        return (
           <KeyboardAvoidingView style={{flex:1}} behavior="padding">

                <Header />

                {childComponent}

                <Button title='Toggle Items' onPress={this.toggleItems} /> 

           </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        );
    }

}

export default Layout;
```

**my complete project on github:** https://github.com/rvmelo/todolist-redux

Is it an error in the code or is it related to some package update?

I get the following error: "**Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.**"

Comment: Can you provide your reducer file?

Comment: Yes I already did

Comment: The error says check render method of `Layout`. Please post your `Layout` component. The error will most likely be there.

Comment: Already posted my Layout.js component

Comment: Can you check if you have export statement in Header component and you are returning JSX?

Comment: ^Same goes for Add screen and todo screen

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to do some tracing down on your end. That error typically comes when you try to render a component that doesn't exist (or doesn't exist at the path you've told it it does), which is impossible to tell without having access to most of the project.

In `AddScreen`, `TodoList`, and `Header` make sure they all `export default`. And if they render any outside components you will need to check the same for them if imported the same way.

One way to debug this would be to remove each component one at a time and see which one makes it break.

-------UPDATE---------

Looking at your project on GitHub, I see that two of the components are named exports.

Change `Layout` to the following:

```js
import { AddScreen } from '../../components/AddScreen/AddScreen';
import { TodoList } from '../../components/TodoList/TodoList';
```

**Explanation**

When you do `export myFunction`, its a *named* export. So you must import it with the named import syntax like this:

```js
import { myFunction } from '..'
```

When you do `export default myFunction`, its a *default* export and can be imported as anything, so you don't use the curly braces and instead do this:

```js
import Anything from '...' //path to myFunction
```

Comment: I already uploaded my project on github. The link is in my post. To run it just type "yarn install" and "yarn start"

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. I'm updating my answer now.

Comment: The alternative to my solution above is to remove your container `consts` and just `export default connect(..`, then you can leave the imports the same. The extra `consts` in your export statements are unnecessary.

Comment: I keep getting the same error after the changes you suggested. Did you manage to run my project?

Comment: No, and I don't have time to. Looks like `Item` has the same problem. You need to go through your project and make sure they are all imported and exported correctly. Both named and default are ok, just make sure you import based on how they are exported.

Comment: Good, hopefully the explanation of why made sense. Also if this was the correct answer can you mark it as accepted?